# Problem passing hex long parameter to COM method using go-ole

Tags: windows, go, dll, com

I'm trying to use go-ole to call COM objects from golang by I think I'm not using correctly paramters form CallMethod and I need some advice.

I have a Visual Basic Script that works fine but I need to do the same from go-lang. This is de VBS that works:

```
 SET xxxx = CREATEOBJECT("XXXX.CPXSrv2")
 nAppID = 0
 nTimeOut = 10
 pVarResult = ""

 nCPxCmd = &H301
 szParam = ";nDevNr=1"
 iRes = xxxx.CPxExecute(nCPxCmd, nAppID, nTimeOut, szParam, pVarResult)
 
 MSGBOX pVarResult
```

CPxExecute method params are defined as follow:

```
void CPXExecute(
        long nCPXCmd,
        long nAppID,
        long nTimeOut,
        LPCTSTR szParam,
        VARIANT* pVarResult
        );
```

My go-lang  code is as follows:

```
// +build windows

package main

import (
//  "time"
    "log"

    ole "github.com/go-ole/go-ole"
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole/oleutil"
)


func main() {

    ole.CoInitialize(0)
    unknown, err := oleutil.CreateObject("XXXX.CPXSrv2")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("CreateObject: ", err)
    }
    xxxx, err := unknown.QueryInterface(ole.IID_IDispatch)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("QueryInterface: ", err)
    }

    r, err1 := oleutil.CallMethod(xxxx, "CPxExecute", 0x0301,0,10,";nDevNr=1")
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal("CallMethod: ", err1, " | ", r)
    }

    xxxx.Release()

    ole.CoUninitialize()
}
```

When I run go process, I get this:

```
CallMethod: The parameter is incorrect. | &{VT_EMPTY 0 0 0 0}
```

I think I have a problem with the type of 0x0301 parameter that is not been correctly sent to COM method because the COMponents log doesn't show any "UKNOWN COMMAND" error but, if I force the VBScript to send a value not known as CPxCmd paramete, at least it shows an error in the log.

If I change  nCPxCmd = &H301 to  nCPxCmd = &H3012 (a value not supported by the COM object) I can see this in the log from the COMponent:

```
INF ExeCOMServer.Instance.Lock
INF Dev1 [ IN] CPxExecute 0x3012, 0, 10, ;nDevNr=1
ERR ERROR: UNKNOWN COMMAND 0x3012
[OUT] CPxExecute 0x3012, ;nError=0x4000000F;szError=Invalid Request!;nExecTime=0
```

But when I call the method from go-lang I get no message, I only get the "ExeCOMServer.Instance.Lock"

```
INF ExeCOMServer.Instance.Lock
```

At least, I'm sure that the Method name "CPxExecute" is correctly send because I have changed it  to a wrong one in go-lang "CPxExecute2" and when I run with this change I get this result:

```
CallMethod: Unknown name. | <nil>
```

So, please, could anybody tell me what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What about the last parameter pVarResult? you may need to pass it in the callmethod, it depends on how go-ole is coded, and also on how the object itself declares this method (typelib, etc.)

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks for your answer. pVarResult is the return from CallMethod.  

'''
func (v *IDispatch) CallMethod(name string, params ...interface{}) (*VARIANT, error) {
'''

And is returning &{VT_EMPTY 0 0 0 0}

Comment: Why don't you pass pVarResult to your CallMethod

Comment: @SimonMourier You are right!!!!! I was confused, I thought pVarResult should be returned by CallMethod bu that is not the case... It works now adding pVarResult as a parameter to CallMethod. Thanks!!!!!